# Min and max media queries in styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a config file for media sizes and I am not knowing how to corporate min and max values for one media type.

I will paste some code

```
const size = {
  mobileS: '320px',
  mobileM: '375px',
  mobileL: '425px',
  tablet: '1024px',
  ipad: '768px',
  laptop: '1024px',
  laptopL: '1330px',
  desktop: '2560px',
};

const device = {
  mobileS: `(max-width: ${size.laptop})`,
  mobileM: `(max-width: ${size.ipad})`,
  ipad: `(max-width: ${size.laptop})`,
  mobileL: `(max-width: ${size.ipad})`,
  tablet: `(max-width: ${size.laptop})`,
  laptop: `(max-width: ${size.desktop})`,
  laptopL: `(max-width: ${size.desktop})`,
  desktop: `(max-width: ${size.desktop})`,
};

export default device;
```

The problem I am trying to solve is to give a min and max value for each screen type so as to have more control because I am having bugs where when i use mobileL as a @media in other components it doesnt give a concrete sizing and the @media for tablet properties overshadow the mobileL even when I am on a mobile screen
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can join two media query conditions with `and`:

```
const device = {
  ipad: `(min-device-width: size.ipad) and (max-device-width: size.mobileS)`,
  // etc...
};
```